# YouTube Analytics vs YouTube Data API Discrepancy

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I've been using the YouTube Analytics API (I'm using the Java library), to retrieve analytics data for a YouTube Channel - I've been filtering the API calls to specific videoIDs.

However the data for the same date range, when I look in YouTube Analytics (the web interface) seems to differ.

Data from the YouTube Web Interface:
[image]

Data from the API:
[image]

Does anyone have an explanation for this ?

Answer (score 2):

It says from this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694483/youtube-analytics-api-demographics-minimum-views-seem-to-be-required-for-query) that it is an intended behavior of both the API and the Youtube Analytics web interface.

To support this similar post, based from the [documentation - How video views are counted](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/2991785?hl=en):

> If you're looking at a video you uploaded, you can monitor your views
>   more closely using YouTube Analytics. However, keep in mind that the
>   [Realtime report](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6096647) only shows estimates of potential view activity and
>   might not match the number you see on the watch page.

Also, there are called **Frozen View Count** where on some videos, the view count might seem frozen or not show all the views that you expect. Video views are algorithmically validated to maintain fair and positive experiences for content creators, advertisers, and users. To verify that views are real and accurate, YouTube may temporarily slow down, freeze, or adjust the view count, as well as discard low-quality playbacks.

Comment: Hi jess, thanks for your answer, however, In YouTube Analytics - I was looking at a watch time report and not the RealTime Report. I am assuming YouTube analytics would be the source of truth for the data, however I would anticipate there could be some sampling - I would like confirmation on that.