# YouTube Analytics API not returning demographic data for channel owner

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, youtube-analytics-api

I am using YouTube Analytics API with oauth2.0 authorization to get channel owner `demographic(ageGroup and gender)`.

It does not return any values for the ageGroup and gender. The `login(authentication)` part works and GAPI loads perfectly as well, but, no values are returned (*even though channel analytics show agegroup and gender*).

Surprisingly, when I use the basic dimensions (*views, likes, comments etc.*), it returns the values properly.

Here is how the response look like:

[image: screenshot]

This is the code:

```
function execute() {       
      return gapi.client.youtubeAnalytics.reports.query({         
           "ids": "channel==MINE",         
           "startDate": "2019-01-01",         
           "endDate": "2022-03-27",         
           "metrics": "viewerPercentage",         
           "dimensions": "ageGroup,gender",           
           "filters": "subscribedStatus==SUBSCRIBED",         
           "sort": "ageGroup,gender"       
       })           
           .then(function(response) {                                    
                 console.log("Response", response);                 
            },                 
      function(err) { console.error("Execute error", err); });     
}
```

Comment: just checking, you are parsing that response body right? (something like `response.json()`)

Comment: @tbjgolden for now, I am just checking it on console. The end goal is to get the individual values(i.e. age13-17) using `response.result` and store them in the database.

Comment: Try this instead to see the actual data: `function execute() { return gapi.etc.etc.then(function(response) { return response.json() }).then(data => {console.log(data)})` - It looks like the `response` you're logging is a [Response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response)

Comment: @tbjgolden thanks, but unfortunately it's not working and giving me an error `Uncaught TypeError: response.json is not a function`. Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

That's because not enough data:

> Understand limited data in YouTube Analytics
>
> We want to give creators
> useful data to make informed decisions about their channel, but some
> data may be limited in YouTube Analytics.
>
> Note: If your video or channel doesn’t have enough traffic during a selected time period, you may not see your data. If you've selected a specific filter, such as geography or gender, you may also not see data
>
> If you want to see more, try extending the time period, or removing filters and breakdowns. Changing these settings may increase the amount of data in the full report.
>
> Types of limited data The following info may be limited:
>
> Demographics data
> Audience data
> Geography data
> Search terms and URLs

source: https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/9101241?hl=en

related post: [YouTube Analytics API - Demographics Minimum Views Seem to Be Required for Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14694483/youtube-analytics-api-demographics-minimum-views-seem-to-be-required-for-query)